# Dockerfile CMD does not get passed with quotes around to /bin/sh -c entrypoint

Tags: docker

I've got a `Dockerfile` that has:

```
ENTRYPOINT /usr/sbin/apache2ctl
CMD ["-D", "FOREGROUND"]
```

However if I view the entrypoint command with `docker ps -a --no-trunc`:

```
81496448b4d3d134ffc4c7fa7d46afd08cb52b608aa07d0b6192993c0e30c7c7   raidenapache1234:latest                                                   "/bin/sh -c /usr/sbin/apache2ctl -D FOREGROUND"                           About an hour ago   Exited (1) About an hour ago                            focused_blackburn
```

It's not passing quotes to `/bin/sh -c` - `/bin/sh -c /usr/sbin/apache2ctl -D FOREGROUND`.

It SHOULD / I intend it to be:
`/bin/sh -c "/usr/sbin/apache2ctl -D FOREGROUND"`

And this fails because:

```
docker run raidenapache1234:latest                  
Usage: /usr/sbin/apache2ctl start|stop|restart|graceful|graceful-stop|configtest|status|fullstatus|help
       /usr/sbin/apache2ctl <apache2 args>
       /usr/sbin/apache2ctl -h            (for help on <apache2 args>)
```

What am I doing wrong...

Comment: Have you tried like this? `CMD ["/usr/sbin/apache2ctl","-D", "FOREGROUND"]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two forms of the `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` statements (and also `RUN`).  If you pass it in the form that looks like a JSON array, *exactly* what you pass in the array is passed along (with no expansion or anything else: `CMD ["ls", "*"]` looks for a single file named exactly `*`).  If you pass a bare string, it gets wrapped in `sh -c`.

The table in the Docker documentation [discussing `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` together](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-cmd-and-entrypoint-interact) has one more detail.  Since your Dockerfile has `ENTRYPOINT` as a bare string, *the `CMD` is completely ignored*.

For routine use I'd suggest just writing this all in a single `CMD`

```
# no ENTRYPOINT
CMD ["/usr/sbin/apache2ctl", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]
```

If you must have an `ENTRYPOINT` then it also needs to use the JSON form

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/sbin/apache2ctl"]
CMD ["-D", "FOREGROUND"]
```

(I prefer to reserve `ENTRYPOINT` for the case of a wrapper script that does some setup and then `exec "$@"` to run the `CMD`; this is a useful pattern and using `ENTRYPOINT` for the binary name makes it difficult.  You also get awkward `docker run --entrypoint ... imagename arg ...` sequences if you need to run some other binary in the container.)